# IBM Watson: Unknown API error when adding documents to the collection

Tags: java, watson-discovery

I am trying to add documents to a collection of my IBM Bluemix Discovery instance via the IBM Watson API in Java. For a given file, I do as follows:

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2017-08-01");
discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api");
discovery.setUsernameAndPassword("{username}", "{password}");
String environmentId = "{environment_id}";
String collectionId = "{collection_id}";

File f = new File("path/to/file");
String path = f.getPath();
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(f.getName());

CreateDocumentRequest.Builder builder = new CreateDocumentRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId).documentId(path).file(f);
CreateDocumentResponse createResponse = discovery.createDocument(builder.build()).execute();
System.out.println(createResponse.toString());
```

However, when I execute my program, I get the error `Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.service.exception.NotFoundException: Unknown API: POST [...]`, which comes from the line where `createResponse` is initialized.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong documentId.

The correct documentId is like "49a82bd4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-900b7378ff35" but you put path as your params.

If you want to add documents, you don't need specify value for documentId by default.

```
Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2017-08-01");
discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api");                             
discovery.setUsernameAndPassword("feeb4a95-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4d94c98b2b24", "KQc6G5nK6HrD");
String environmentId = "59d0fa32-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cf98a8cdc52e";
String collectionId = "49a82bd4-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-900b7378ff35";
File f = new File("/Users/xxx/Desktop/myDoc.json");
Path path = Paths.get(f.getPath());
InputStream documentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(path));

//Create
CreateDocumentRequest.Builder builder = new CreateDocumentRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId);
builder.inputStream(documentStream, HttpMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
CreateDocumentResponse createResponse = discovery.createDocument(builder.build()).execute();
//Retrieve  (You can get documentId here)
QueryRequest.Builder queryBuilder = new QueryRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId);
QueryResponse queryResponse = discovery.query(queryBuilder.build()).execute();
System.out.println(queryResponse.toString());
//Delete
String documentId = "d1059598-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b65a1f3334d8";
DeleteDocumentRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteDocumentRequest.Builder(environmentId, collectionId, documentId).build();
DeleteDocumentResponse deleteResponse = discovery.deleteDocument(deleteRequest).execute();
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. However, now I would have anohter question. If I want to search a specific document given its path, how can I do it ? I would need the document Id and it seems that the latter is given only once in the response of `CreateDocumentRequest`. Do I have to save these Ids mapped to the corresponding path in a file ? The same problem applies for deleting documents.